# Is it possible to render different components depending on a url params value within the same url in react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So basically title is my question. Is it possible to achieve something like this with only url paramater change:

<Route path={'/users/:id'} component={()=> UsersPage}/>

<Route path={'/users/:filterOption'} component={()=> UsersList}/>

Comment: Old thread, I know, but in case you haven't thought about it, how should react-router be able to tell if what eg, `users/3` is meant to contain – an id or a filterOption? That's probably why there was a misunderstanding in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `react-router-dom@5`

Yes, absolutely you can. The `Router` component ***inclusively*** matches and renders routes (as opposed to the `Switch` component that ***exclusively*** matches them). This means the `Router` will render all routes and redirects that are matched by the `path` prop.

Given path `"/users/someValue":

```
<Router>
  <Route path={'/users/:id'} component={()=> UsersPage}/>
  <Route path={'/users/:filterOption'} component={()=> UsersList}/>
</Router>
```

Both components can be matched and rendered.

### Note about `Route` `component` prop!

[Route render methods](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods)

When you use `component` (instead of `render` or `children`) the router uses `React.createElement` to create a new React element from the given component. ***That means if you provide an inline function to the component prop, you would create a new component every render. This results in the existing component unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just updating the existing component.*** When using an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or the children prop.

This means you should not use the `component` prop if you are providing a function. Instead do one of the following

```
<Router>
  <Route path={'/users/:id'} component={UsersPage}/>
  <Route path={'/users/:filterOption'} component={UsersList}/>
</Router>
```

or

```
<Router>
  <Route path={'/users/:id'} render={()=> <UsersPage />}/>
  <Route path={'/users/:filterOption'} render={()=> <UsersList />}/>
</Router>
```

or

```
<Router>
  <Route path={'/users/:id'}>
    <UsersPage />
  </Route>
  <Route path={'/users/:filterOption'}>
    <UsersList />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

## `react-router-dom@6`

`react-router-dom@6` now always exactly matches and uses a path ranking/scoring system and  `'/users/:id'` and `'/users/:filterOption'` have the same specificity and will have the same score. There's nothing to disambiguate between them. Instead you'll rendering a single route and need to use the `useParams` hook to read the route param, either in a wrapper component or directly in the routed components.

Example with wrapper component.

```
const UserWrapper = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return (
    <>
      <UsersPage id={id} />
      <UsersList filterOption={id} />
    </>
  );
};
```

...

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path={'/users/:id'} element={<UserWrapper />} />
    ...
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Comment: Sorry if i didn't undestand something, but in this example both components will render at the same time, no? How do i 'tell' to the Router that i want only one component to render depending on my ulr parameter? Right now Router 'sees' some parameter after '/users/' and renders both components. Should i do something like this inside my components (in this example UsersPage, which expects id as a url parameter ) : if (!params.id) return <div></div>

Comment: @nonamenoname Oh, have I misunderstood your question? Are you wanting only one route/component to be matched and rendered? If so, then invert the order of the routes and render them into a `Switch` component. I will update my answer if this is the case.

Comment: Just to clear things out: I want to render <UsersPage/> component when /movies/{id} url is matched and I want to render <UsersList/> when /movies/{option} is matched. I use these parameters in my components as an argument that I pass to my dataFetching function, so I can set current page information depending on the url.However, there are two problems I cannot find solution to: 1. React renders both components at once. 2.Even though I defined type of url parameters inside each copmponent, I still get access to the current url parameter whether or not it matches my type definiton.

Comment: I guess I should do the url parameter check inside my component? But in this case I should return emty div-element if parameter is not matched with expected type . Is there a simple way of achieving this result? Of course I could change url completely and solve it this way, but I want to keep first part of the url unchanged.

Comment: @nonamenoname I see. Then no, "/movies/:id" and "/movies/:option" have the same specificity and there's no way to differentiate them. Whichever is listed first for matching is the one that will be matched and rendered. If you need to differentiate them then I suggest different routes, "/movies/id/:id/" and "/movies/option/:option" for example, or use a queryString parameter, like `path="/movies/:id"` and "/movies/id1234?option=true" for example.

Comment: "but I want to keep first part of the url unchanged." Would placing the differentiator *after* the param work? I.E. "/movies/:id/id" and "/movies/:option/option".

Comment: Okay, I'll just change my url path, thank you for explaing me all of this!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, we can do that in react-router, Just check this [article](https://dev.to/annequinkenstein/til-react-router-2-dynamic-url-parameters-ccf#:%7E:text=URL%20parameters%20are%20parameters%20whose,change%20based%20off%20of%20it.&text=The%20%3Atool%20and%20%3Aname%20parts,be%20considered%20as%20variable%20parameters.), it has best example for Dynamic URL Parameters.